# Object in for loop is blank after first cycle

Tags: python-3.x

This is a test. I have hexlifyed the length of these files names and concatenated the names and the hexlified lengths together. In this order (Length,Name). Now i am attempting to read the file using this code,

```
import binascii

test = ('TEST_.txt')

with open(test, 'rb') as infile_:
    infile_read = infile_.read()

start = (0)

for files in range(0, 20):

    name_len = infile_read[(start) : ((start) + (2))]

    name_len =  int.from_bytes((name_len), byteorder='big')

    file_name = infile_read[((start) + (2)) : ((name_len) + (2))]

    print(name_len)

    print(file_name)

    start = ((start) + (name_len) + (2))
```

txt file,

"TEST_.txt"
b'\x00\ntest_0.png\x00\ntest_1.png\x00\ntest_2.png\x00\ntest_3.png\x00\ntest_4.png\x00\ntest_5.png\x00\ntest_6.png\x00\ntest_7.png\x00\ntest_8.png\x00\ntest_9.png\x00\x0btest_10.png\x00\x0btest_11.png\x00\x0btest_12.png\x00\x0btest_13.png\x00\x0btest_14.png\x00\x0btest_15.png\x00\x0btest_16.png\x00\x0btest_17.png\x00\x0btest_18.png\x00\x0btest_19.png\x00\x0btest_20.png'

returns this,

```
>>>10
>>>b'test_0.png'
>>>10
>>>b''
>>>10
>>>b''
...
```

i wont it to return this,

```
>>>10
>>>b'test_0.png'
>>>10
>>>b'test_1.png'
>>>10
>>>b'test_2.png'
...
```

The lengths print correctly but the names only print once. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple here, im not sure how i missed it.

This,

```
file_name = infile_read[((start) + (2)) : ((name_len) + (2))]
```

Needs to be,

```
file_name = infile_read[((start) + (2)) : ((start) + (name_len) + (2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to another approach, you could just `split` on the character `\x00` (i've added in the `strip` to remove the other kinds of whitespace that occur in your string):

```
filenames = infile_read.split(b'\x00')
for name in filenames:
   name = name.strip()
   print (len(name))
   print (name)
0
b''
10
b'test_0.png'
10
b'test_1.png'
10
b'test_2.png'
10
b'test_3.png'
10
b'test_4.png'
...
```

Comment: No the approach must be as i specified. No other way will work for what i am  doing.